# How to display the Text on the iPhone lock screen

Tags: ios, iphone

Is there any way to display the small(about 5-6 lines) text on the iPhone lock screen. I have searched this topic on google but didn't find anything.
And also is there any way to display the text on the springboard rather than notification.

Comment: Adding such edits to your question context makes your question off-topic and can also be considered rude. If you have queries related to certain rules of SO please feel free to ask them in http://meta.stackoverflow.com/.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not clear what exactly you are asking for, I'm assuming that you are questioning about push notification as like shown in the image. [image: iphone with push notification on loach screen]

If so, refer the link to proceed: click [here](http://maniacdev.com/2011/05/tutorial-ios-push-notification-services-for-beginners)

Comment: As far as I know push notification is the only way to achieve this kinda messages..

Comment: Yes, you are right. But i want the similar results without the push notification is that possible? Otherwise push notification is also a way..+1

Comment: UILocalNotification is the other way..